# What is $\int_Byd(x,y)?$

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Let $T=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2:x,y\le 1,\; -x^2\le y\le 1-x,\; y\ge 0,\; -y^2\le x\le 1-y,\; x\ge 0\}$. My question: How to determine $$\int_Byd(x,y)?$$
I would start with $\int_Byd(x,y)=\int_0^1(\int_{-x^2}^{1-x}ydy)dx$, but I'm not sure if this is correct.

Comment: The lower bound $-x^2$ in your inner integral is not correct. I give you some time to try to fix it yourself, though...

Comment: Make a drawing! That helps a lot when doing double integrals.

Comment: d(x,y) is dxdy ? First time I see this notation !

Comment: @FabriceNEYRET: I think ${\rm d}(x,y)$ for the (unsigned) Lebesgue measure and $dx\wedge dy$ for the $2$-form are very fine notations, while $dxdy$ is somehow dangling in the air.

Comment: with or without the exterior product it's classical, but at least in France I never met d(x,y). But after all dP or dr in physics, and P = r = (x,y), so it does make sens ! :-)

Comment: Comment to the question (v1): Presumably $B=T$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Notice that the region $T$ is the triangle

$$T~=~\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2 | x,y\ge 0 \wedge x+y \le 1\}.$$

So the integral  is

$$I~=~\int_T\! y~d(x,y)~=~\int_0^1(\int_{0}^{1-x}\!y~dy)dx~=~\ldots~=~\frac{1}{6}.$$